# time-based encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption

I've an idea in my mind but I've no idea what the magic words are to use in Google - I'm hoping to describe the idea here and maybe someone will know what I'm looking for.

Imagine you have a database.  Lots of data.  It's encrypted.  What I'm looking for is an encryption whereby to decrypt, a variable N must at a given time hold the value M (obtained from a third party, like a hardware token) or it failed to decrypt.

So imagine AES - well, AES is just a single key.  If you have the key, you're in.  Now imagine AES modified in such a way that the algorithm itself requires an extra fact, above and beyond the key - this extra datum from an external source, and where that datum varies over time.

Does this exist?  does it have a name?

Comment: Similar to how an RSA key works, perhaps?  Where the "current password" changes over time at a rate known to the server and to an authorized client?  In security-speak, something you can search is "two-factor security."  There are, to my knowledge, three primary security factors.  Something you know (a password), something you have (an access card, an RSA keychain fob, etc.), something you are (fingerprint, retina scan, etc.).  Each additional factor adds considerably more security than just doubling one of the factors. (Password + RSA key is better than 2 passwords, for example.)

Comment: It's like that, except more so - it's actually for how the data is encrypted, not just for authentication.  Consider that my situation is reversed.  Rather than the agent contacting me and me needing to authenticate the agent (RSA), in my case the agent (database) holds everything of value, but it's encrypted; I want to make sure the agent can only access the data *with my permission*, e.g. such that if the agent is subverted, he still cannot access the data without my permission.  Normal AES encryption isn't useful for this because the agent will already have to know the key.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3064/is-it-possible-to-make-time-locked-encrytion-algorithm and http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography

Comment: lols, there's a cryptography stackexchange - thankyou, Code.  I've just read the links, they're not really what I have in mind, although interesting.  I think my key question is can the decrypt algorithm require a fact which varies over time - almost like multiparty encryption.

Comment: I don't know the answer. You can get something like this from identity-based encryption (IBE). In this case the identity includes the time, like "bob_129210" but of course these is more to it then that. And you can get something like this from one-time password (OTP) schemes where the password at time t is the hash pre-image of the password at time t-1.

Comment: I think it is called a trusted third party that will only give you the symmetric key given a particular time slot :) You are then supposed to throw it away (as you already have access to the DB, you could also decrypt it and save it somewhere). Anything else will require additional parties I would think (but the world is weird).

Comment: @GregS: right, but remember - we have say a petabyte of encrypted data.  We can't re-encrypt it.  A OTP key would be useful if the encrypted data could be decrypted by many keys, but where any given key is valid for only a short defined period.

Comment: I don't think the encryption key can change on a static file. Julian Assange learned that the hard way. But if the actual database access is through an interface you control, then you can change the encryption key any time you want.

Comment: @user82238 I hope you don't mind that I ran a bounty on your question.   :)

Answer (score 16):

This is easy to do with the help of a trusted third party.  Yeah, I know, you probably want a solution that doesn't need one, but bear with me — we'll get to that, or at least close to that.

Anyway, if you have a suitable trusted third party, this is easy: after encrypting your file with AES, you just send your AES key to the third party, ask them to [encrypt it with their own key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_wrap), to send the result back to you, and to publish their key at some specific time in the future.  At that point (but no sooner), anyone who has the encrypted AES key can now decrypt it and use it to decrypt the file.

Of course, the third party may need a lot of key-encryption keys, each to be published at a different time.  Rather than storing them all on a disk or something, an easier way is for them to generate each key-encryption key from a secret master key and the designated release time, e.g. by applying a suitable [key-derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to them.  That way, a distinct and (apparently) independent key can be generated for any desired release date or time.

In some cases, this solution might actually be practical.  For example, the "trusted third party" might be a tamper-resistant [hardware security module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) with a built-in real time clock and a secure external interface that allows keys to be encrypted for any release date, but to be decrypted only for dates that have passed.

---

However, if the trusted third party is a remote entity providing a global service, sending each AES key to them for encryption may be impractical, not to mention a potential security risk.  In that case, [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) can provide a solution: instead of using [symmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_encryption) to encrypt the file encryption keys (which would require them either to know the file encryption key or to release the key-encryption key), the trusted third party can instead generate a public/private key pair for each release date and publish the public half of the key pair immediately, but refuse to disclose the private half until the specified release date.  Anyone else holding the public key may encrypt their own keys with it, but nobody can decrypt them until the corresponding private key has been disclosed.

(Another partial solution would be to use [secret sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) to split the AES key into the shares and to send only one share to the third party for encryption.  Like the public-key solution described above, this would avoid disclosing the AES key to the third party, but unlike the public-key solution, it would still require two-way communication between the encryptor and the trusted third party.)

---

The obvious problem with both of the solutions above is that you (and everyone else involved) *do* need to trust the third party generating the keys: if the third party is dishonest or compromised by an attacker, they can easily disclose the private keys ahead of time.

There is, however, a clever method [published in 2006 by Michael Rabin and Christopher Thorpe](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cat/tlc.pdf) (and mentioned in [this answer on crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3064/is-it-possible-to-make-time-locked-encrytion-algorithm/3072#3072) by one of the authors) that gets at least partially around the problem.  The trick is to [distribute the key generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_key_generation) among a network of *several* more or less trustworthy third parties in such a way that, even if a limited number of the parties are dishonest or compromised, none of them can learn the private keys until a sufficient majority of the parties agree that it is indeed time to release them.

The Rabin & Thorpe protocol also protects against a variety of other possible attacks by compromised parties, such as attempts to prevent the disclosure of private keys at the designated time or to cause the generated private or public keys not to match.  I don't claim to understand their protocol entirely, but, given that it's based on a combination of existing and well studies cryptographic techniques, I see no reason why it shouldn't meet its stated security specifications.

Of course, the major difficulty here is that, for those security specifications to actually amount to anything useful, you do *need* a distributed network of key generators large enough that no single attacker can plausibly compromise a sufficient majority of them.  Establishing and maintaining such a network [is not a trivial exercise](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12580/why-is-time-lapse-cryptography-not-popular).

Comment: Interesting that the Rabin and Thorpe paper link is ftp. Here's an updated link: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cat/tlc.pdf

Comment: @DanielQue: Thanks. I've updated the link in the answer to use yours.

Comment: `he trick is to distribute the key generation among a network of several more or less trustworthy third parties in such a way that, even if a limited number of the parties are dishonest or compromised, none of them can learn the private keys until a sufficient majority of the parties agree that it is indeed time to release them` - I like this a lot - kinda like a Raft protocol for encryption/access control! (+1).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the kind of encrpytion you are looking for exists. It is called **timed-release encryption**, or abbreviated **TRE**. Here is a paper about it: http://cs.brown.edu/~foteini/papers/MathTRE.pdf

The following is an excerpt from the abstract of the above paper:

*There are nowdays various e-business applications, such as sealedbid auctions and electronic voting, that require time-delayed decryption of encrypted data. The literature oers at least three main categories of protocols that provide such timed-release encryption (TRE).
They rely either on forcing the recipient of a message to solve some time-consuming, non-paralellizable problem before being able to decrypt, or on the use of a trusted entity responsible for providing a piece of information which is necessary for decryption.*

I personally like another name, which is "time capsule cryptography", probably coined at [crypto.stackoverflow.com: Time Capsule cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography).

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer is no: the key used to decrypt the data cannot change in time, unless you decrypt and re-encrypt all the database periodically (I suppose it is not feasible).

The solution suggested by @Ilmari Karonen is the only one feasible but it needs a trusted third party, furthermore, once obtained the master AES key it is reusable in the future: you cannot use 'one time pads' with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your token to be time-based you can use [TOTP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm)

TOTP can help you generate a value for variable N (token) at a given time M. So the service requesting the access to your database would attach a token which was generated using TOTP. During validation of token at access provider end, you'll validate if the token holds the correct value based on the current time. You'll need to have a Shared Key at both the ends to generate same TOTP.

The advantage of TOTP is that the value changes with time and one token cannot be reused.

I have implemented a similar thing for two factor authentication.

"One time Password" could be your google words.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called Public Key Cryptography or Public Key Encryption.
Another good word to google is "asymmetric key encryption scheme".

Google that and I'm quite sure you'll find what you're looking for.
For more information [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

An example of this is : [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

Edit (putting things into perspective)
The second key can be determined by an algorithm that uses a specific time (for example at the insert of data) to generate the second key which can be stored in another location.

Answer (score 0):

As other guys pointed out One Time Password may be a good solution for the scenario you proposed.

There's an [OTP implemented in C#](https://code.google.com/p/otpnet/) that you might take a look https://code.google.com/p/otpnet/.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we want a generator that depends on the time, but I don't know any algorithm that can do that today.

More generally, if Alice wants to let Bob know about something at a specific point in time, you can consider this setup:

Assume we have a public algorithm that has two parameters: a very large random seed number and the expected number of seconds the algorithm will take to find the unique solution of the problem.

- Alice generates a large seed.
- Alice runs it first on her computer and computes the solution to the problem. It is the key. She encrypts the message with this key and sends it to Bob along with the seed.
- As soon as Bob receives the message, Bob runs the algorithm with the correct seed and finds the solution. He then decrypts the message with this key.

Three flaws exist with this approach:

- Some computers can be faster than others, so the algorithm has to be made in such a way as to minimize the discrepancies between two different computers.
- It requires a *proof of work* which may be OK in most scenarios (hello Bitcoin!).
- If Bob has some delay, then it will take him more time to see this message.

However, if the algorithm is independent of the machine it runs on, and the seed is large enough, it is guaranteed that Bob will not see the content of the message before the deadline.